# How to check if line is in the following format X.X.X.X

Tags: bash, shell-script

I already have :

```
$p =~ ^[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]$
```

but this only works for numbers, how can I make it so that it includes words and regardless of size.

For example:

```
this.should.definitely.work
```

would be valid and

```
this1.should.definitely.work2
```

would be valid too

Comment: You really need to define "words". You have shown lowercase letters and digits. How do you feel about punctuation, special characters like # " ' | ~ = $ % ^, even BEL and STX and other controls.

Comment: Your original pattern only allows for a single digit at the end.  Should the pattern that you are looking for in this question match `...` (three dots), or does there need to be something between the dots? What's a "word"? Does it include `:` or `-` or capital letters?

Answer (score 0):

The most accurate regex pattern for your case would be:

```
^[^[:space:].]+\.[^[:space:].]+\.[^[:space:].]+\.[^[:space:].]+$
```

Answer (score 0):

I've come to this solution:

```
foo="this1.should.definitely.work2"
[[ $foo =~ ^.*\..*\..*\..*$ ]] && echo "match"
```

Comment: But this doesn't meet requirements. It would also match x.x.x.x.x and so on..

Comment: @EOhm You are right.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `[[:alnum:]]` class that stands for letters and digits:

```
$p =~ ^[[:alnum:]]+\.[[:alnum:]]+\.[[:alnum:]]+\.[[:alnum:]]+$
```

Comment: Does that work in Bash on some system? `\w` is a Perl regex thing, and even there, it matches a single character. Bash uses POSIX EREs, which doesn't have those `\x` character classes. On my systems `\w` matches a literal `w`. (I can't remember if it's defined that way or left undefined in the standard.)

Comment: @ilkkachu To my knowledge single-letter class equivalents are POSIX ERE. [Reference](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_38_0/libs/regex/doc/html/boost_regex/syntax/basic_extended.html). The `[:word:]` class is explicitly mentioned in `man bash` under section **Pattern Matching** (however interestingly no mentioning of the single-letter replacement).

Comment: note how that document says "The POSIX standard defines no escape sequences for POSIX-Extended regular expressions, except that: ... However, that's rather restrictive, so the following standard-compatible extensions are also supported by Boost.Regex:" and then it starts with 'Escapes matching a specific character' and then '"Single character" character classes'

Comment: The standard says under [9.4.2 ERE Ordinary Characters](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2018edition/basedefs/V1_chap09.html#tag_09_04_02): "An ordinary character is an ERE that matches itself. An ordinary character is any character in the supported character set, except for the ERE special characters listed in ERE Special Characters. **The interpretation of an ordinary character preceded by an unescaped <backslash> ( '\\' ) is undefined**, except in the context of a bracket expression (see ERE Bracket Expression)." (I don't know why there's a double backslash in the parens)

Comment: In any case, it doesn't work with Bash on Debian or Mac. Some GNU utils do support `\w` though (but not all other such classes...), so `echo foo |grep '\w'` does match.

Comment: @ilkkachu And now I see where my test failed: I relied on `grep -G` but.... `man grep`: "In GNU grep there is no difference in available  functionality  between basic and extended syntaxes." - Thanks for the correction!

Comment: That comment about available functionality seems to be more about GNU supporting stuff like `\|` in BRE to stand for the ERE alternation `|` etc. (standard BREs don't have alternation at all). `\<`, `\w`, `\b` and others are just nonstandard extensions in both.

Comment: It's actually `[[:word:]]` (so stuff like `[[:alpha:]_]` works), and it matches only one character, so what you want is probably `[[:word:]]+`

Comment: @ilkkachu Well, even this fails: `[[ a1b2 =~ [[:word:]] ]] ; echo $?` (returns code 2 for bad syntax). Quite the opposite of the own manual. Talk about testing your code ...

Comment: right, I seem to remember hearing about that one. It works in Bash's pattern matches (e.g. `[[ foo = *[[:word:]]* ]]` is true), but not in regexes. Might have been something about Bash implementing pattern matches itself vs. using the system libraries for regexes, but I'm not sure